# ISSET and GET in PHP

Tags: php

Is this an efficient way of converting the url ?p=XX to displayed content?

`<?php if (isset($p[include ($_GET['p'] . '.php')])) ?>`

---

Other bonus question:

I'm using xampp, why cant I use the `<?` or `<?=` tags rather than `<?php` and `<?php echo` respectively.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your first question? What do you mean by `efficient way of converting the url ?p=XX to displayed content`

Comment: Can you maybe come up with a catchier title for your question?

Comment: -blank stare- Even as a php n00b, as you call yourself, how in the world can you possibly write that and expect it to work?????

Comment: And what is this code supposed to do? Seems rather nonsensical.

Comment: Regarding the <? problem,you need to set 'short_open_tag' to be 'ON' in your php.ini file

Comment: **Chuck Norris** can't even make sense of your title.

Comment: Hilarious! Maybe I should change it to "php noob and illiterate too!"

Comment: Even in Stackoverflow, Chuck Norris lurks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You propably are looking for this solution?

```
<?php

    if ( isset( $_GET['p'] ) && isset( $p[ $_GET['p'] ] ) ) {
        include( $_GET['p'] . ".php" );
    }

?>
```

Comment: why the two issets? out of curiosity because i dont see what they are doing there

Comment: When I'm interpreting your code (which is awfully wrong ;) )right, you're trying to find out if _GET['p'] is set and if the value out of _GET['p'] is set as an key in the Arrays $p. If so: include the file thats referenced by the value. These both tests are done by using isset.

Comment: I don't know why it worked, but it was working for me. I didn't think it looked right though. So the first isset is seeing if the url contains anything for "?p=" and the second isset is looking to see if it has an assigned value? I don't have $p assigned. --- Basically just want the url's p value to be converted into the filename and included. Do I still need both issets?

Comment: I see what you did there. You have GLOBALS activated, that way you can access $_GET['p'] also via $p. You should avoid this technique at all costs as it implies a serious security issue. What you are trying to do is: `include( $_GET['p'] . '.php' )` the isset is obslete at this point as the inclusion is done *before* the isset test is done. It of course returns false. Your should avoid this technique as well, by this way one has the possibility to include *any* file in your php-script (even remote files from other servers!), thus compromising your whole machine.

Comment: Sorry, most of what you're saying is foreign to me, since this is my first go at a php driven website/cms eventually. Globals, would that be in php.ini? Also would I continue to use the solution you originally provided or would I want to change it to achieve what I want? - Which option is the most secure.

Comment: Look here for the register_globals issue: [link](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) You shouldn't in any case use the solution you first introduced. look at this paste: [link](http://pastebin.com/mimSCgMV) that is a valid solution that implies no security issues. if you have any questions, feel free to ask!

Comment: You could abbreviate this to `isset($_GET['p'], $p[$_GET['p']])`... :)

Comment: you're right, but i wanted to give a simple to understand solution.

Answer (score 1):

I can answer your bonus question.

`<?` and `<?=` only work if you have `shorttags` enabled. You shouldn't use them anyway. Ever. Learn that now while you still can.

Comment: Ditto. Don't ever use short tags. `<?` can overlap with xml declarations, for one thing. I never understood why they were allowable in the first place.

Comment: Even more confusing is why `<%` is allowable as a PHP opening tag...

Comment: Saved from a bad habit...thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's many ways to handle what you want to do. A common one would be to store information such as a page ID or name in a database, then take your p variable that you are pulling from the header, and grab the data you want.

Also, find your php.ini file (\xampp\php), and turn on short_open_tag.

As a not, this is not a good idea because not all servers you may want code on will support short tags. So if you wanted to migrate, you would have quite a bit of work ahead of you.